# Sync Google Site with Google Apps Account

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps, google-contacts-api, google-sites

I have a Google Site based on this template https://sites.google.com/site/theintranetsitetemplate/. It exists in the company's Google Apps domain account. I would like to know if there is a way to sync the documents page with Google Docs and the directory page with Google Contacts directory. If so, does this require Google Apps Script?

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a Google Drive folder gadget that points to the shared folder.

1. In editing mode on a page, click Insert > Drive > Folder.
2. Browse to the folder to share (or paste the folder's URL in the box). Be sure that the folder is shared with the public, or this will not work.

Sharing out a domain's full directory is not easy (even suggesting it would make many IT depts queasy), but defintely can be done with an Apps Script (see the [dev page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/contacts/)).